# Pycharm's icon on my desktop

Tags: pycharm

I've successfully installed `Pycharm` on my computer. However, I'm not able to install the icon in my desktop.

[image]

After executing this command, the window opened correctly.

**Question :** How could I import the icon in my Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

In Pycharm 2016
Tools => Create Desktop Entry